# Calculate maximum outputs of numbers

Tags: php, jquery, math, matrix

I am creating a filter which uses multiple input value to compare with each other and find some matches if they have some common data Example:

if i use 4 inputs with values a,b,c,d then maximum compression can come something like this

```
Input: 1-2
Input: 1-3
Input: 1-4
Input: 2-3
Input: 2-4
Input: 3-4
```

here we not included  1-1,2-2,3-3 and 4-4 also 2-1,3-1... cause 1-2 or 2-1 have same compassion and that is a-b and b-a.. Now i want to create this output for given numbers of output...so i am looking for some Php or Jquery solution to create a loop and find output.

Comment: Nothing i have no idea how can i achieve this :)

Comment: @SUnilMEena you need to Try. And if you have any error post here ...

Comment: just give a hint so i can start..

Comment: @SUnilMEena I'll give you a hint. You need two nested loops. Assuming you have `N` values, first loop should iterate from `1` to `N-1`, second from `current+1` to `N`. This way you'll get all possible pairs.

Comment: Thanks for helping :) i

Answer (score 0):

This is called handshaking problem, studied in out school time.

```
<?php
$peoples = ["a","b","c","d"];
for($i=0;$i<count($peoples);$i++){
  for($j=$i+1;$j<count($peoples);$j++){
    echo "$peoples[$i] will handshake with $peoples[$j]\n";
  }
}
?>
```

Check demo : https://eval.in/608543

Comment: @SUnilMEena : Your welcome dear, I know you tried yourself , but you should post your try in StackOverflow, We all are here to learn and help each other.

Comment: @SUnilMEena if an answer solves your problem you should select it. Also upvote it and any other answer you found helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$size = 4;//number of inputs
$output = [];
for($i=1;$i<$size;$i++){
    for($j=$i+1;$j<=$size;$j++){
        $output[] = "Input: $i-$j \n";
    }
}
echo implode("",$output);
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/qlYl4)

Comment: Thanks this exactly what i needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can also try this

```
<?php
$data = array("a","b","c","d");
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
  for($j=$i+1;$j<count($data);$j++){
    echo "input :" ."$data[$i]"." - "."$data[$j]"."</br>";
  }
}
?>
```